# mod_wsgi install Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi, redhat

I am trying to installing mod_wsgi for my python flask web application.

I have python 2.6 and 2.7 on my ec2 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4.

I am using RMP because, I am automating this process using puppet.

```
yum -y install python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Setting up Install Process
Examining python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64.rpm: python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64
Marking python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python27-mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.4-9.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd24-httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664 for package: python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64 (/python27-mod_wsgi-3.4-9.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

I have link as required and suggested by others on my system.

```
find / -name libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/libpython2.7.so.1.0

#ldd /usr/local/bin/python2.7
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff647ff000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f215d9b6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003e1f000000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003e1e800000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003e21c00000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003e1f800000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e1ec00000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e1e400000)
```

Please let me know why I am still getting this error?

Comment: And yes I have tried **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib** and **Add /usr/local/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig**

Answer (score 1):

The same problem to me. Getin confused.....

my way is compiling source code.

Downloading source code from : https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

Whatever version you want, be careful that it's better to take a version bigger than 3.5 for some security issue.

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.2.8.tar.gz
```

tar zxvf https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.2.8.tar.gz

enter into the source directory, and then

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-python=/usr/bin/python
make
make install
```

and then I guess your problem will disappear.

Attention: if you compile python independently, you must add share flag with you configure

```
./configure --enable-shared
make && make install
```

Orelse there will be no libpython2.7.so.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting  the same error and solved by installing **python27-libs**.